# Удалить и посчитать дубли из массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Можно удалить дубли из массива и параллельно записывать, сколько дублей было удалено в отдельный массив?

То есть, у меня есть массив, где один из ключей это дата (показывает кол-во переходов за день), я хочу удалить одинаковые даты и оставить только одну. При этом показывать сколько было дублей в каждом из дней (это покажет переходы за день). Спасибо!

Текущий массив времени Unix:

```
$times = [1557262800000,1557262800000,1257262800000];
```

Нужно довести до:

```
$day_time = [1557262800000,1257262800000];
$transit = [2, 1] // 2 и 1 тк было два дубля далее один
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вас правильно понял?

```
<?php 

$array = [151,151,167,167,167,333];

$temp = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (!isset($temp[$item])) $temp[$item] = 0;

    $temp[$item]++;
}

print_r($temp); // [151 => 2, 167 => 3, 333 => 1]

$day_time = array_keys($temp);

print_r($day_time); // [0 => 151, 1 => 167, 2 => 333]

$transit = array_values($temp);

print_r($transit); // [0 => 2, 1 => 3, 2 => 1]
```

Ну или по наводке  @u_mulder можно так:

```
print_r(array_count_values($array)); // [151 => 2, 167 => 3, 333 => 1]
```

Comment: Функция array_count_values уже изобретена

Comment: @u_mulder спасибо, я дополню ответ